# Is there a better way to convert a stream of code points into a string in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, sequence

I have a sequence of code points as `Sequence<Int>`.

I want to get this into a `String`.

What I currently do is this:

```kotlin
val string = codePoints
    .map { codePoint -> String(intArrayOf(codePoint), 0, 1) }
    .joinToString()
```

But it feels extremely hairy to create a string for each code point just to concatenate them immediately after. **Is there a more direct way to do this?**

So far the best I was able to do was something like this:

```kotlin
val string2 = codePoints.toList().toIntArray()
    .let { codePoints -> String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.size) }
```

The amount of code isn't really any better, and it has a `toList().toIntArray()` which I'm not completely fond of. But it at least avoids the packaging of everything into dozens of one-code-point strings, and the logic is still written in the logical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either go for the simple:

```kotlin
val string = codePoints.joinToString("") { Character.toString(it) }
// or
val string = codePoints.joinToString("", transform = Character::toString)
```

Or use a string builder:

```kotlin
fun Sequence<Int>.codePointsToString(): String = buildString {
    this@codePointsToString.forEach { cp ->
        appendCodePoint(cp)
    }
}
```

This second one expresses exactly what you want, and may benefit from future optimizations in the string builder.

> it feels extremely hairy to create a string for each code point just to concatenate them immediately after

Did you really measure a performance issue with the extra string objects created here? Using `toList()` would also create a bunch of object arrays behind the scenes (one for each resize), which is a bit less, but not tremendously better. And as you pointed out `toIntArray` on top of that is yet another array creation.

Unless you know the number of elements in the sequence up front, I don't believe there is much you can do about that (the string builder approach will also likely use a resizable array behind the scenes, but at least you don't need extra array copies).

Comment: The extra strings plus the backing arrays were indeed creating a ton of garbage. It would kill me if the code were running frequently but I was willing to ignore it because it might end up being run-once code. Runs once, but runs a lot of times at startup. `toList()` _may_ expand per resize but for streams at least usually depends on whether you know the size of the stream. Not sure about sequences, I'd hope that they have the same optimisation but I don't actually know. `Character.toString(int)` and `appendCodePoint(int)` are both news to me anyway, so I learned at least two things today.

Comment: *toList() may expand per resize* - sequences are lazy by nature so they don't expose any size in their API. Since most of the collection operations are extension functions (not virtual OO methods), there is rarely a specific implementation of the operation for a specific implementation of iterable/sequence, which means you always have to rely on a starting default capacity and then expand

Comment: Interesting... maybe a reason to stick with Stream. It's lazy, _and_ you get the size when it's possible. :)

Comment: I have never been in a situation where the difference mattered that much, to be honest

Comment: You should try implementing text decoding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = codePoints.map { Character.toString(it) }.joinToString("")
```

Edit, based on Joffrey's comment below:

```
val result = codePoints.joinToString("") { Character.toString(it) }
```

Additional edit, full example:

```
val codePoints: Sequence<Int> = sequenceOf(
  'a'.code,
  Character.toCodePoint(0xD83D.toChar(), 0xDE03.toChar()),
  Character.toCodePoint(0xD83D.toChar(), 0xDE04.toChar()),
  Character.toCodePoint(0xD83D.toChar(), 0xDE05.toChar())
)

val result = codePoints.joinToString("") { Character.toString(it) }

println(result)
```

This will print: a

Comment: Note that `map` can be merged with  `joinToString`, which accepts a transform function. Although this still doesn't remove the OP's concern about creating one string per code point before concatenating them

Comment: What's the point of calling `toCodePoint` via a function reference? You're building a sequence via the `sequenceOf` constructor, which means all arguments will be evaluated right away anyway (it doesn't make them lazy)

Comment: There is no specific reason besides making the construction of the example data explicit (with surrogate pairs).

Comment: But the new edited code is also explicit, and yet it doesn't use the method reference indirection that was used before

Comment: I do not know how to do it differently (for characters which need a low surrogate too).

Comment: I could insert _128515_ for the first emoji, but that doesn't make it explicit enough IMHO. Also the OP states that _I have a sequence of code points as Sequence<Int>._, so does it really matter how the example data is constructed? But I am really curious how it could be done simpler – it would be great to know. It is not the first time I stumbled across it, and I never found another solution.

Comment: To be more precise: ''.code is not possible, because '' is not a Char.

Comment: Wait I think you misunderstood my first comment. I was specifically objecting about the method *reference* and its immediate invocation: `(Character::toCodePoint)(...)`. I'm not saying you should use a different method. The edited code is definitely ok.

Comment: I just wanted to add _val high = 0xD83D;
val low = 0xDE05;
val cp = (high - 0xD800) * 0x400 + low - 0x2400_ as another way of calculating a code point...